# Is copying in a loop less efficient than memcpy()?

Tags: c++, performance, loops, memcpy, strlen

I started to study IT and I am discussing with a friend right now whether this code is inefficient or not.

```
// const char *pName
// char *m_pName = nullptr;

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(pName); i++)
    m_pName[i] = pName[i];
```

He is claiming that for example memcopy would do the same like the for loop above. I wonder if that's true, I don't believe.

If there are more efficient ways or if this is inefficient, please tell me why!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [memcpy vs for loop - What's the proper way to copy an array from a pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729046/memcpy-vs-for-loop-whats-the-proper-way-to-copy-an-array-from-a-pointer)

Comment: why don't you just check a memcpy implementation?

as an example:
https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.22/string_2memcpy_8c_source.html
https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.22/generic_2memcopy_8h.html

Comment: The point about using `memcpy()` is, that it's usually heavily optimized. `memcpy()` will, for instance, not read/write single bytes like your loop does. But in your case, you should be looking at `strncpy()` instead, because that will avoid the second pass through the string to compute its length.

Comment: @zenith Killed the c tag since `nullptr` was mentioned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I took a look at [actual `g++ -O3` output for your code](http://goo.gl/3RznYp), to see just how bad it was.

`char*` can alias anything, so even the `__restrict__` GNU C++ extension can't help the compiler hoist the `strlen` out of the loop.

I was thinking it would be hoisted, and expecting that the major inefficiency here was just the byte-at-a-time copy loop.  But no, it's really as bad as the other answers suggest.  `m_pName` even has to be re-loaded every time, because the aliasing rules allow `m_pName[i]` to alias `this->m_pName`.  **The compiler can't assume that storing to `m_pName[i]` won't change class member variables, or the src string, or anything else.**

```
#include <string.h>
class foo {
   char *__restrict__ m_pName = nullptr;
   void set_name(const char *__restrict__ pName);
   void alloc_name(size_t sz) { m_pName = new char[sz]; }
};

// g++ will only emit a non-inline copy of the function if there's a non-inline definition.
void foo::set_name(const char * __restrict__ pName)
{
    // char* can alias anything, including &m_pName, so the loop has to reload the pointer every time
    //char *__restrict__ dst = m_pName;  // a local avoids the reload of m_pName, but still can't hoist strlen
    #define dst m_pName
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(pName); i++)
        dst[i] = pName[i];
}
```

Compiles to this asm (g++ -O3 for x86-64, SysV ABI):

```
...
.L7:
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rbp+0+rbx]      ; byte load from src.  clang uses mov al, byte ..., instead of movzx.  The difference is debatable.
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [r12]           ; reload this->m_pName    
        mov     BYTE PTR [rax+rbx], dl         ; byte store
        add     rbx, 1
.L3:                                 ; first iteration entry point
        mov     rdi, rbp                       ; function arg for strlen
        call    strlen
        cmp     rbx, rax
        jb      .L7               ; compare-and-branch (unsigned)
```

Using an `unsigned int` loop counter introduces an extra `mov  ebx, ebp` copy of the loop counter, which you don't get with either `int i` or `size_t i`, in both clang and gcc.  Presumably they have a harder time accounting for the fact that `unsigned i` could produce an infinite loop.

So obviously this is horrible:

- a `strlen` call for every byte copied
- copying one byte at a time
- reloading `m_pName` every time through the loop (can be avoided by loading it into a local).

Using `strcpy` avoids all these problems, because **`strlen` is allowed to assume that it's src and dst don't overlap.**  Don't use `strlen` + `memcpy` unless you want to know `strlen` yourself.  If the most efficient implementation of `strcpy` is to `strlen` + `memcpy`, the library function will internally do that.  Otherwise, it will do something even more efficient, like [glibc's hand-written SSE2 `strcpy` for x86-64](http://www.sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S;h=caa74be2c2278cb418fa4fa75e824b84d82aceda;hb=1233be76694ca81454f61e2ba5a2fb5830840191).  (There is a [SSSE3 version](http://www.sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-ssse3.S;hb=1233be76694ca81454f61e2ba5a2fb5830840191), but it's actually slower on Intel SnB, and glibc is smart enough not to use it.)  Even the SSE2 version may be unrolled more than it should be (great on microbenchmarks, but pollutes the instruction cache, uop-cache, and branch-predictor caches when used as a small part of real code).  The bulk of the copying is done in 16B chunks, with 64bit, 32bit, and smaller, chunks in the startup/cleanup sections.

Using `strcpy` of course also avoids bugs like forgetting to store a trailing `'\0'` character in the destination.  If your input strings are potentially gigantic, using `int` for the loop counter (instead of `size_t`) is also a bug.  Using `strncpy` is generally better, since you often know the size of the dest buffer, but not the size of the src.

`memcpy` can be more efficient than `strcpy`, since `rep movs` is highly optimized on Intel CPUs, esp. IvB and later.  However, scanning the string to find the right length first will always cost more than the difference.  Use `memcpy` when you already know the length of your data.

Answer (score 5):

At best it's somewhat inefficient. At worst, it's *quite* inefficient.

In the good case, the compiler recognizes that it can hoist the call to `strlen` out of the loop. In this case, you end up traversing the input string once to compute the length, and then again to copy to the destination.

In the bad case, the compiler calls `strlen` every iteration of the loop, in which case the complexity becomes quadratic instead of linear.

As far as how to do it efficiently, I'd tend to so something like this:

```
char *dest = m_pName;

for (char const *in = pName; *in; ++in)
    *dest++ = *in;
*dest++ = '\0';
```

This traverses the input only once, so it's potentially about twice as fast as the first, even in the better case (and in the quadratic case, it can be *many* times faster, depending on the length of the string).

Of course, this is doing pretty much the same thing as `strcpy` would. That may or may not be more efficient still--I've certainly seen cases where it was. Since you'd normally assume `strcpy` is going to be used quite a lot, it can be worthwhile to spend more time optimizing it than some random guy on the internet typing in an answer in a couple minutes.

Comment: g++ doesn't hoist `strlen` out of the loop.  I'm pretty sure this is because aliasing rules allow `char*` to alias anything.  See my answer.  Also, calling `strcpy` will get you an optimized library implementation that will perform much better for large strings (e.g. copying 16B at a time with SSE).  Writing out byte-copy loops "manually" should be avoided when there's a library function that might be optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on interpretation of *efficiency*. I'd claim using `memcpy()` or `strcpy()` more efficient, because you don't write such loops every time you need a copy.

> He is claiming that for example memcopy would do the same like the for loop above.

Well, not exactly the same. Probably, because **`memcpy()`** takes the size once, while `strlen(pName)` might be called with every loop iteration potentially. Thus from potential performance *efficiency* considerations `memcpy()` would be better.

---

BTW from your commented code:

```
// char *m_pName = nullptr;
```

Initializing like that would lead to undefined behavior without allocating memory for `m_pName`:

```
char *m_pName = new char[strlen(pName) + 1];
```

Why the `+1`? Because you have to consider putting a `'\0'` indicating the end of the c-style string.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code is inefficient. Your code takes what is called "O(n^2)" time. Why? You have the strlen() call in your loop, so your code is recalculating the length of the string every single loop. You can make it faster by doing this:

```
unsigned int len = strlen(pName);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    m_pName[i] = pName[i];
```

Now, you calculate the string length only once, so this code takes "O(n)" time, which is much faster than O(n^2). This is now *about* as efficient as you can get. However, A memcpy call would still be 4-8 times faster, because this code copies 1 byte at a time, whereas memcpy will use your system's word length.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's inefficient, not because you're using a loop instead of `memcpy` but because you're calling `strlen` on each iteration. `strlen` loops over the entire array until it finds the terminating zero byte.

Also, it's very unlikely that the `strlen` will be optimized out of the loop condition, see [In C++, should I bother to cache variables, or let the compiler do the optimization? (Aliasing)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33898371/3425536).

So `memcpy(m_pName, pName, strlen(pName))` would indeed be faster.

Even faster would be [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy), because it avoids the `strlen` loop:

```
strcpy(m_pName, pName);
```

`strcpy` does the same as the loop in @JerryCoffin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

For simple operations like that you should almost always *say what you mean* and nothing more.

In this instance if you had meant `strcpy()` then you should have said that, because `strcpy()` will copy the terminating NUL character, whereas that loop will not.

Neither one of you can win the debate.  A modern compiler has seen a thousand different `memcpy()` implementations and there's a good chance it's just going to recognise yours and replace your code either with a call to `memcpy()` or with its own inlined implementation of the same.

It knows which one is best for your situation.  Or at least it probably knows better than you do.  When you second-guess that you run the risk of the compiler failing to recognise it *and* your version being worse than the collected clever tricks the compiler and/or library knows.

Here are a few considerations that you have to get right if you want to run your own code instead of the library code:

- What's the largest read/write chunk size that is efficient (it's rarely bytes).
- For what range of loop lengths is it worth the trouble of pre-aligning reads and writes so that larger chunks can be copied?
- Is it better to align reads, align writes, do nothing, or to align both and perform permutations in arithmetic to compensate?
- What about using SIMD registers?  Are they faster?
- How many reads should be performed before the first write?  How much register file needs to be used for the most efficient burst accesses?
- Should a prefetch instruction be included?

  - How far ahead?
  - How often?
  - Does the loop need extra complexity to avoid preloading over the end?
- How many of these decisions can be resolved at run-time without causing too much overhead?  Will the tests cause branch prediction failures?
- Would inlining help, or is that just wasting icache?
- Does the loop code benefit from cache line alignment?  Does it need to be packed tightly into a single cache line?  Are there constraints on other instructions within the same cache line?
- Does the target CPU have dedicated instructions like `rep movsb` which perform better?  Does it have them but they perform *worse*?

Going further; because `memcpy()` is such a fundamental operation it's possible that even the *hardware* will recognise what the compiler's trying to do and implement its own shortcuts that even the compiler doesn't know about.

<s>Don't worry about the superfluous calls to `strlen()`.  Compiler probably knows about that, too.</s> (Compiler should know in some instances, but it doesn't seem to care)  Compiler sees all.  Compiler knows all.  Compiler watches over you while you sleep.  <s>Trust the compiler.</s>

Oh, except the compiler might not catch that null pointer reference.  Stupid compiler!

Comment: +1 for mentioning copying in bigger chunks.  However, it turns out that `strlen` can't be hoisted out, because `char*` can alias anything.  Also, no, CPUs don't generally recognize block-copy loops and peephole-optimize them.  I've never heard of any architecture doing that.  Aliasing rules mean this loop has different semantics from `strcpy`, so the compiler can't replace it with something optimal.

Comment: @PeterCordes, for `strlen()` you're quite right.  The compiler _does_ detect non-aliasing conditions and do the hoist, but those conditions are rarer than I'd thought (mostly through failure to terminate the string before the end of the object, but then the outcome should be undefined anyway so hoisting should be benign... but gcc doesn't see it that way).  I don't expect a CPU to peephole anything (although soft ones might), but to implement pipeline optimisations for known idioms.  They often go undocumented, for various reasons, though.

Comment: What would you call a "pipeline optimization"?  http://agner.org/optimize/ documents the pipelines of modern x86 CPUs in pretty fair detail.  There's nothing special about a copy loop that the pipeline and OOO machinery handles differently.  It's just a bunch of byte loads and stores.  It will have extra slowdowns if there is false aliasing between the load and store addresses.  (e.g. offset by 4k)

Comment: @PeterCordes proprietary CPUs and DSPs, mostly.  Typically in-order pipelines that would otherwise stumble on tight memcpy loops because of the round trip through the register file.

Comment: Oh, and also where the icache or instruction buffer have funny constraints and you have to ensure that the loop is fully within a single cache line and that there are no other branches in the same cache line or buffer.  Not _exactly_ a pipeline optimisation, but constraints that the compiler won't impose automatically on _every_ branch or label because it would burn up so much icache.

Answer (score 1):

This code is confused in various ways.

1. Just do `m_pName = pName;` because you're not actually copying the string.
   You're just pointing to the one you've already got.
2. If you want to copy the string `m_pName = strdup(pName);` would do it.
3. If you already have storage, `strcpy` or `memcpy` would do it.
4. In any case, get `strlen` out of the loop.
5. This is the wrong time to worry about performance.
   First get it right.
6. If you insist on worrying about performance, it's hard to beat `strcpy`.
   What's more, you don't have to worry about it being right.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, why do you need to copy at all ??? (either with the loop or memcpy)

if you want to duplicate a memory block, thats a different question, but since its a pointer all you need is &pName[0] (which is the address of the first location of the array) and sizeof pName ... thats it ... you can reference any object in the array by incrementing the address of first byte and you know the limit using the size value ... why have all these pointers ???(let me know if there is more to that than theoretical debate)

Comment: Sometimes you do need to copy, e.g. before reusing the src buffer for something else.  Minimizing copies is a good suggestion, but not a complete answer to this question.

Comment: yes very true ... but he is starting out the code with a pointer to the beginning of a string (end of string defined by the null termination) which is a very efficient system where you can fully describe a memory block using only starting address and the null termination, and trying to make a pointer to each and every byte of the string till the null termination. (why on earth ??) if you want to make a copy, then copy the block not the pointers ... if you want to have an extra pointer, then copy only first address, ie new pointer ... but an array of pointers ??? that was beyond me !!

Comment: No, his loop is just a badly-written `strcpy`.  He's not storing a pointer to each char.

Comment: ohhhh ... I see now ... seems I have been working here for too long !!