# Question regarding converting assembly to c -- specifically what the movzbl instruction does?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, instructions, zero-extension

I am trying to figure out what this in assembly would mean in C:

```
movq 16(%rdi), %rdx
movq 16(%rsi), %rax
movzbl (%rdx), %edx
```

I am mostly confused about what the movzbl (%rdx), %edx will do. Thanks!

Comment: Well, this is what `movq`  does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3852919/8658157, and this for `movzbl`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9318005/8658157

Comment: `movzbl (%rdx), %edx` reads a single byte from memory address [rdx] and zero extends the byte so it is 32-bits wide with the upper 24 bits set to zero and stores it in EDX. As well it also zero extends the 32-bit EDX register through the entire RDX register (it sets the upper 32-bits of RDX to 0) because in 64-bit mode when a destination register is a 32-bit register the upper 32-bits of the corresponding 64-bit register are set to zero automatically by the CPU. In essence it reads one byte from [RDX] and sets the low byte of RDX to the byte read and ensures the upper 56 bits are zero.

Answer (score 1):

This is [AT&T syntax](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html#Instruction-Naming) for the [`movzx`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movzx) instruction.  It fetches one byte from the address contained in `%rdx`, zero-extends it to 32 bits, and stores the result in `%edx`.

As with every x86-64 instruction that writes to a 32-bit register, [the high half of the corresponding 64-bit register `%rdx` is also zeroed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6)  So you may also think of this instruction as zero-extending an 8-bit value to 64 bits.

Comment: I think it is worth bringing up that the upper 32-bits of RDX are also set to zero automatically by the CPU since the destination (EDX) is a 32-bit register. The end result really is that the lower 8 bits of RDX are set to the byte read and the upper 56 bits are set to 0