# Quick workaround for SSE2 movq instruction on non-SSE2 CPUs

Tags: x86, sse, inline-assembly, sse2

How could I convert a `movq` SSE2 instruction into a simple code snippet which I could later patch into the original EXE which cointained? Please if you could provide sample direct instructions to be used as a replacement "template", so much the better!

I am mostly interested in writing such template-based replacement into my CodeBlocks project using C mostly, so I'd prefer it to be inline ASM form. That way I could programatically patch the subst into original instructions which are 5-byte long with an ASM call to the inline piece of code within the same C I'm using to patch the EXE (rest of the code already written).

I know the question sounds a bit more general than you'd like maybe, but any insight will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852909/movq-assembly-function

Comment: Just to clarify: in the case in which I had say an `movq %xmm0, [some memory location]`   (this is CodeBlocks in Linux), I got it when the XMM0 reg was 0, e.g. `xor %eax, %eax` and then patch it over two consecutive DWORDS at that location. But what if there's significant value charged previously in XMMn?  How can I "discharge" the value into "normal" registers to drop afterwards into memory?  (sorry I know quite my way in x86 standard ASM but had no experience previously with SSE/SSE2...)

Comment: @DanielA.White thanks, not sure if applicable.Are there any standard way of halving so to speak a `movq`into two halves that would execute in SSE2-less CPU?  Do I need to use standard registers in the way?  Is there any SSE2-less "write half of XMMn into DWORD" that I could use twice for the current loaded FP value?  I'm confused because I've seen some other SSE (not 2 I guess) instructions that the CPU treats & executes normally. It's just a couple of movq's in the original code that I'm bothered with!  (this is compiled code, if I had the source I could recompile with SSE2-less swtich/es...)

Answer (score 1):

With only MMX/SSE, the options are limited.

A `movq` from memory eg `movq xmm4, [edx]` may be emulated with:

```
xorps xmm4, xmm4
movlps xmm4, [edi]
```

A `movq` to memory eg `movq [edx], xmm5` may be emulated with:

```
movlps [edx], xmm5
```